# Access slot from S4 object in a list within an R loop

Tags: r, vcf-variant-call-format

I am trying to access a specific slot from an object inside a list in an R loop:

```
mysamples<-'a_vcf', 'b_vcf', 'c_vcf'
```

```
for(i in mysamples){
vcf<-mget(i)
a<-vcf$i@rowRanges
}
```

But this is not working:

```
Error in eval(quote(list(...)), env) : 
  trying to get slot "rowRanges" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
```

`mget()` generates a list called `vcf` which contains an S4 object named `i` (for example: `a_vcf`); but, using `vcf$i`instead of `vcf$a_vcf` does not work.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `$` operator this way - you have to use the `[[` operator instead. So if your structure is set up as you describe, that is you have lists called `a_vcf`, `b_vcf`, `c_vcf`, each of which contains an element with the same name, then the following will work:

```r
for(i in mysamples){
vcf <- mget(i)
a <- vcf[[i]]@rowRanges
}
```

However, please remember you are over-writing `a` each time, so after the loop completes, you will only have the value of `c_vcf$c_vcf@rowRanges` written to `a`.